# Add windows authentication functionality in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis, package, script-task

I am currently uploading document on sharepoint using ssis script task.
Also I have a table where I am having user name and password from where the script task is fetching the same to login on sharepoint.
My question is how to replace this with windows authentication so that there is no need to preserve such sensitive information in a table.
As am new to C# coding, please help me in writing the code for replacing the code to fetch windows current user logged on.

Comment: What did your google find you?

Comment: To add windows.Security.Principal Namespace.

Comment: then keep reading - there is way more info than that

Comment: Thanks! :) That's what am doing.

Comment: Thanks! Am able to crack it :)